# Finding some examples (triangle equality)

Tags: functional-analysis

I need to find some example of a vectors $x$,$y$ from $C[a,b]$, $l_1$, $L_1(X, \mu)$ and from somewhere else such that $\begin{Vmatrix} x + y\end{Vmatrix} = \begin{Vmatrix} x \end{Vmatrix} + \begin{Vmatrix} y\end{Vmatrix}$ but which are linear independent.
(the point of it is that we can check this way that some given space cannot be Hilbert one)
 I've never been good in finding examples but I suppose these are well known.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- $C([a,b])$ (assuming it's equipped with sup norm): $a=0, b=1$ and $x = \cos$, $y =1$.
- $\ell_1$: $x=(1,0,0,\ldots)$ and $y=(0,1,0,0,\ldots)$.
- $L_1(X,\mu)$: $X= (0,\infty)$, $\mu =\text{Lebesgue}$, $f(x) = e^{-x}$ and $g(x) = \chi_{(0,1)}(x)$.